# Add log in credentials to PHP file command

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to read a file from a web address that requires log in.  I have my parameter as:

```
 $data = file("http://rotoguru1.com/cgi-bin/mlb-dbd-2016.pl?&start=$dt");
```

The website defines the log in with:
Username
Access Key

```
 <form name=login action=http://rotoguru1.com/cgi-bin/getcred.pl method=POST >
  <input name=geturl type=hidden value="http://rotoguru1.com/cgi-bin/mlb-dbd-2016.pl?" >
 Username: &nbsp;<input name=user type=text length=20 value= ><br>
 Access key: <input name=key type=password length=11 > &nbsp; 
 <input type=submit value="Log in" ><br></form></td>
```

How do I add these definitions to my script?

Comment: seeing you're using a `.pl` (perl script), I added the tag for it, could be relevant for those who know perl. Yet, you tagged as mysql; why?

Comment: First check how the site is accepting usrname,passwd, I mean GET/POST method, also check for hidden input type , and create php request to site accordingly!

Comment: btw, you have a huge security hole in your perl script.

Comment: please don't dump code in comments, edit your question to contain it. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37501022/edit

Comment: this is not my perl script.  This site does not hold state secrets, it holds daily baseball statistics.  I'm trying to add them to a mysql database.  I just don't know how to "log in" via my script.

Comment: Please post the http method in form tag.

Comment: this isn't relevant to perl really at all it doesn't seem. The perl code is server-side, which OP probably doesn't even have access to.

Comment: @stevieb I thought at first it did (perl tag) seeing the only piece of code in the question. I removed it now.

Answer (score 0):

This code will send parameters to perl script , and read it's response which will be, complete HTML code, along with HTTP response headers, so you have to deal with it as well!

```
$url = "http://rotoguru1.com/cgi-bin/getcred.pl";
$usrname=''; // user name here
$access='';//your access key here
$myvars = 'user='.$usrname.'&key='.$access;

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);     
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$resp = curl_exec( $ch );
```

Comment: What does cURL do and what is this code doing?  I'm trying to understand documentation on cURL but it seems as though this code might be opening and closing a session?  My goal is to access a flat file via web address.  You can see an example here:http://rotoguru1.com/cgi-bin/mlb-dbd-2016.pl?